# How to properly close gather tasks if some of them take too long

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have code that looks like

```
async def watch_task1():
    while not stop:
        await client.ws.get_data()

async def watch_task2():
    while not stop:
        await client.ws.get_news()

async def stop_after():
    global stop
    await client.sleep(60)
    stop = True

async def main():
    tasks = [
        watch_task1(),
        watch_task2(),
        stop_after(),
    ]

    try:
        await gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

My problem here, is that `client.ws.get_data()` and `client.ws.get_news()` do not receive messages often. And so it can take 24h before the `await client.ws.method` gets a message and thus the program stops, while I want it to stop after 60 seconds max, whether the tasks have finished or not.

How could I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a connection timeout with asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756507/how-can-i-add-a-connection-timeout-with-asyncio)

Comment: Use `asyncio.wait_for(gather(client.ws.get_data(), client.ws.get_news()), timeout=60)`. You don't actually need `stop_after`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either wrap each task in an `asyncio.wait_for` method, so that each has a timeout - or, instead of `.gather`, use `asyncio.wait`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait  - it even has an optional `timeout` argument. The only thing is that you'd better wrap it in a looping pattern, if you want to retry some of the not-completed tasks. (but otherwise, if you will just handle all not-done tasks in the same way, for example, passing then to a long-running manager task, just one call will do)

```
async def main():
    tasks = [
        watch_task1(),
        watch_task2(),
        stop_after(),
    ]

    
    done, waiting = await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=60, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
    for task in done:
        try:
            # but check the docs, there are better ways to check for exceptions. I am just transposing your code
            task.result()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    # at this point you have the uncompleted tasks in the `waiting` set, and can do whatever you want to them.
    ...
    for task in waiting:
       task.cancel()
```