# Timeout for python coroutines

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine, python-sockets

How can I make a coroutine stop with timeout?

I don't understand why asyncio.wait_for() doesn't work for me.
I have such piece of code (planning to make my implementation of telnet client):

```
def expect(self, pattern, timeout=20): 
    if type(pattern) == str:
        pattern = pattern.encode('ascii', 'ignore')        
    return self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(self.asyncxpect(pattern), timeout))

async def asyncxpect(self, pattern): #receives data in a cumulative way until match is found
    regexp = re.compile(b'(?P<payload>[\s\S]*)(?P<pattern>%s)' %pattern)
    self.buffer = b''
    while True:
        # add timeout
        # add exception handling for unexpectedly closed connections
        data = await self.loop.sock_recv(self.sock, 10000) 
        self.buffer += data
        m = re.match(regexp, self.buffer)
        if m:
            payload = m.group('payload')
            match = m.group('pattern')
            return payload, match
```

As I thought this code, at some point (in await statement) returns control to event loop. I thought it should happen when there is no more data to receive.
And if event loop has control, it can stop with timeout.

But if server doesn't send anything useful (that matched) my code just stumbles in this loop, right at await point.

I think it is different from this problem [Python asyncio force timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609534/python-asyncio-force-timeout), because I'm not using blocking statements like time.sleep(n).

[Here is my code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dug1ftdzfct7c3f/telxpect.py?dl=0)

Comment: I think it is different from this problem "Python asyncio force timeout", because I'm not using blocking statements like time.sleep(n).

Comment: As the comment indicates, this is indeed quite different from the other question, where the issue is in using blocking call in an async function. See my answer for details.

Comment: Hi, this was very long time ago, thank you anyway:)

Comment: No problem, you asked your question before I got interested in asyncio. I stumbled upon it by accident, thinking how sad it was that an actually interesting question was incorrectly marked as duplicate - but sometimes StackOverflow is like that. Glad to have helped.

Comment: I've still not learned asyncio that well :) probably need to use it every day, to remember...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the server closes the connection, `sock_recv` returns an empty bytearray (`b''`), indicating end of file. Since you don't handle that condition, your code ends up stuck in an infinite loop processing the same buffer.

To correct it, add something like:

```
if data == b'':
    break
```

...after the `data = await loop.sock_recv(...)` line.

But the above still doesn't explain why `wait_for` is unable to cancel the rogue coroutine. The problem is that `await` doesn't mean "pass control to the event loop", as it is sometimes understood. It means "request value from the provided awaitable object, yielding control to the event loop **if** (and as long as) the object indicates that it does not have a value ready." The *if* is crucial: if the object *does* have a value ready when first asked, this value will be used immediately without ever deferring to the event loop. In other words, `await` **doesn't guarantee that the event loop will get a chance to run.**

For example, the following coroutine completely blocks the event loop and prevents any other coroutine from ever running, despite its inner loop consisting of nothing *but* awaiting:

```py
async def busy_loop():
    while True:
        await noop()

async def noop():
    pass
```

In your example, since the socket does not block at all when it is at end-of-file, the coroutine is never suspended, and (in collusion with the above bug) your coroutine never exits.

To ensure that other tasks get a chance to run, you can add `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in a loop. This should not be necessary for most code, where requesting IO data will soon result in a wait, at which point the event loop will kick in. (In fact, needing to do so often indicates a design flaw.) In this case it is only in combination with the EOF-handling bug that the code gets stuck.

Comment: I've forgot asyncio quite a bit. Could you please tell me in short, how does the object "indicates that it does not have a value ready"? or how does it indicate the opposite?

Comment: @ЕвгенийАртеменко In case of `sock_recv`, it goes ahead and tries to read from a non-blocking socket. If it gets some data, it means the socket was readable ("the opposite"), and the data is returned. If the read returns -1/EWOULDBLOCK, the coroutine suspends, immediately after having registered the descriptor with the event loop so as to wake it up once the socket becomes readable. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) for a demonstration of how such a system can be implemented. (Asyncio works a bit differently, but the basic idea is the same.)

Comment: I wanted to know what asyncio uses for the "indication", but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ЕвгенийАртеменко The linked video actually covers that part as well. In asyncio, [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a31f4cc881992e84d351957bd9ac1a92f882fa39/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L341) awaits a freshly created `Future`; since it does not have a value associated with it, awaiting it automatically suspends the coroutine. (The future does that by having an `__await__` whose implementation uses a generator that yields.)

Comment: With generator-based coroutines, the generator yielding indicates suspension, and the generator returning (raising `StopIteration`) indicates completion.