# Asyncio Queue waits until it is full before get returns something

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-asyncio

I'm having a weird issue with `asyncio.Queue` - instead of returning an item as soon as it available, the queue waits until it is full before returning anything. I realized that while using a queue to store frames collected from `cv2.VideoCapture`, the larger the `maxsize` of the queue was, the longer it took to show anything on screen, and then, it looked like a sequence of all the frames collected into the queue. 
Is that a feature, a bug, or am i just using this wrong? 
Anyway, here is my code

```
import asyncio  
import cv2  
import numpy as np  


async def collecting_loop(queue):  
    print("cl")  
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
    while True:  
        _, img = cap.read()  
        await queue.put(img)  


async def processing_loop(queue):  
    print("pl")  
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  
    while True:  
        img = await queue.get()  
        cv2.imshow('img', img)  
        cv2.waitKey(5)  


async def main(e_loop):  
    print("running main")  
    queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=e_loop, maxsize=10)
    await asyncio.gather(collecting_loop(queue), processing_loop(queue))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()   
try:   
    loop.run_until_complete(main(e_loop=loop))   
except KeyboardInterrupt:   
    pass   
finally:   
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is [the queue getter not waking up until the queue fills up] a feature, a bug, or am i just using this wrong?

You're using it wrong, but in a subtle way. As Andrew explained, `queue.put` doesn't guarantee a task switch, and the collector coroutine only runs blocking code and `queue.put`. Although the blockade is short, asyncio doesn't know that and thinks you are invoking `queue.put` in a really tight loop. The queue getters simply don't get a chance to run until the queue fills up.

The correct way to integrate asyncio and cv is to run the cv code in a separate thread and have the asyncio event loop wait for it to finish. The `run_in_executor` method makes that really simple:

```
async def collecting_loop(queue):  
    print("cl")  
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
    while True:  
        _, img = await loop.run_in_executor(None, cap.read)
        await queue.put(img)
```

`run_in_executor` will automatically suspend the collector  coroutine while waiting for a new frame, allowing for the queued frame(s) to be processed in time.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `await q.put()` **doesn't switch** to another task every call. Actually it does only when inserting a new value is *suspended* by *queue-full* state transition.

Inserting `await asyncio.sleep(0)` **forces** task switch.
Like in multithreaded code `file.read()` doesn't enforce OS thread switching but `time.sleep(0)` does.

Misunderstandings like this are pretty common for newbies, I've discussed very similar problem yesterday, see [github issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus/issues/82).

**P.S.**

Your code has much worse problem actually: you call *blocking synchronous* code from async function, it just is not how asyncio works.

If no asynchronous OpenCV API exists (yet) you *should* run OpenCV functions in a separate thread.

Already mentioned [janus](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus) can help with passing data between sync and async code.

Comment: "The problem is that `await q.put()` **doesn't switch** to another task every call." This sounds almost like a bug - couldn't `put()` suspend when it detects that there are waiters? Or is this the case of correctly written code not needing to rely on exactly when the switch happens?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. You propose *alternative* strategy by prioritizing getters to putters. Viable solution but `asyncio.Queue` uses another approach: put everything until the queue is not full. This way is simple from both implementation **and** teaching perspective. People should learn that `await` doesn't force *context switch* anyway -- that's how asyncio works (not only queues but all awaits).

Comment: You're right. To even observe this issue, you must either fill the queue really fast - in which case it will soon become full anyway - or call synchronous code in the same loop, as the OP does with `cap.read()`. The latter is not correct usage of asyncio, even if it appears to work in simple scenarios. I wrote an answer recommending invocation of `cap.read` with `loop.run_in_executor`, which will ensure the needed switch.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816319/1600898) is another baffling example of the `await`-not-guaranteed-to-switch confusion - even explicitly calling into IO doesn't guarantee that a switch will happen.

Comment: While searching for other examples that use OpenCV with asyncio I found [this (first code block)](http://deklund.com/blog/2015/12/3/asynchronous-constraint-of-memory-allocation). It shows a similar flaw, right? Even though it uses `await asyncio.sleep(0)` the `cap.read()` is running in the main thread. And it seems to pile up tasks, never gathering them.

Comment: `cap.read()` is the blocking call, it should be used in asyncio thread pool