# How can I pause & resume a task in asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Let's say I have a background task that's looping through existing orders (doing some manipulations if necessary).
Now if I want to add an order, this background task should stop while I'm placing a new order and resume when I am finished.

In pseudo-code:

```
async def loop_orders():
    while True:
        do_this()
        do_that()
    return

async def create_order():
    stop_loop_orders()
        ...
        send_order()
    resume_loop_orders()
    return
```

I couldn't figure out which of these two is the way to go:

- [asyncio.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#lock): What is locked? How do I define what should be locked?
- [asyncio.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event): The wait() method would "*Wait until the event is set.*" => but I would rather need a "*wait **if** the event is set*" functionality.

Comment: when you start create_order then you should set value in `lock` and unset it at the end of `create_order`. And `loop_order` should always check this `lock` and skipe functions: `if not lock: do_this() do_that()`

Comment: with `Event` you would think in different way: instead of `wait if the event is set` you can use `wait if the event is **unset**/**clear**` but I don't know if it will work as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to suspend and restart tasks in async python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66687549/is-it-possible-to-suspend-and-restart-tasks-in-async-python)

Comment: Thanks for your hints. @VPfB's example helped me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot suspend and resume an asyncio task.

You could cancel the task and later create a new one, but this leads to more problems than it solves. Data consistency may be compromised and the new task will not resume exactly where the previous one was interupted.

You could easily make the task wait at some specific point (or points)

```
async def loop_orders():
    while True:
        ... wait here while paused ...
        do_this()
        do_that()
```

but when the `create_order` pauses the `loop_orders` task, the former must wait until the latter reaches that point where it pauses - the `create_order` task requests a pause and the `loop_orders` acknowledges.

I made a little demo with two `Events` that I named `enable` and `idle` in an attempt to make the method names `.clear`, `.set` and `.wait` match the logic.

```
import asyncio

enable = None
idle = None

async def loop_orders():
    while True:
        idle.set()
        await enable.wait()
        idle.clear();
        print("processing order ... ", end="", flush=True)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.7)
        print("done")

async def create_order():
    enable.clear();
    await idle.wait()
    print("-- pause start ... ", end="", flush=True)
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("stop")
    enable.set()

async def test():
    global enable, idle

    enable = asyncio.Event()
    enable.set()    # initial state = enabled
    idle = asyncio.Event()

    asyncio.create_task(loop_orders())
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await create_order()
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await create_order()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("EXIT")


asyncio.run(test())
```

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was

```
lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def loop_orders():
    while True:
        if not lock.locked():
            do_this()
            do_that()

async def create_order():
    async with lock:
        send_order()
```

So before sending order it sets `lock` so `if not lock.locked():` should skip `do_this() do_that()`. But code can run somewhere inside `do_this() do_that()` and then `lock.locked()` can't stop it. So maybe it should be in both

```
lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def loop_orders():
    while True:
        async with lock:
            do_this()
            do_that()

async def create_order():
    async with lock:
        send_order()
```

This way when it starts sending then it has to wait with `do_this() do_that()`. And when it starts `do_this() do_that()` then it has to wait with `send_order()`

---

**BTW:**

If you want to understand it then in normal code it could look like

```
lock = False

async def loop_orders():
    global lock

    while True:

        # wait if `lock` was set `True` in other function(s)
        while lock:         
            pass

        # set `True` to block other function(s)
        lock = True

        do_this()
        do_that()

        # set `False` to unblock other function(s)
        lock = False

async def create_order():
    global lock

    # wait if `lock` was set `True` in other function(s)
    while lock:
        pass

    # set `True` to block other function(s)
    lock = True

    send_order()

    # set `False` to unblock other function(s)
    lock = False
```

---

**BTW:**

I think you could use `Event` in similar way but you should think in different way: instead of `wait if the event is set` you can use `wait if the event is **unset**/**clear**`

Comment: Task C (create) should block the task L (loop). But the two tasks have 50:50 chance to get the lock. It means that often the task L blocks the task C. Not sure the OP wanted that.

Comment: @VPfB I don't have full working code to test if my idea is good. It was only some idea to show direction but not full solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should maybe consider implementing this as a producer/consumer pattern using a Queue.

But if you really want to suspend the execution of a `Task`, you can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66687549/is-it-possible-to-suspend-and-restart-tasks-in-async-python).