# what's the difference of calling a normal function from async function with await a coroutine from an async function?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

1. ```
   async def caller():
       await bar()
       print("finish")

   async def bar():
      // some code here
   ```
2. ```
   async def caller():
       bar()
       print("finish")

   def bar():
      //some code here
   ```

In above example. caller has to wait for the completion of bar() for both cases. Any difference for bar to be a normal / coroutine for this situation? If we want to "await" some functions, why not just use a normal function.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that in the second example `bar()` is a non-async function, so it *itself* cannot await anything. For example, if you wanted to access a web service from within `bar()`, it wouldn't be a problem in the first example, you'd just use [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/). In the second example it would be pretty much impossible, as async libraries require being used from async functions, and non-async libraries will block the whole event loop while waiting for response.

> If we want to "await" some functions, why not just use a normal function.

If the function you await doesn't need to communicate with the outside world (e.g. if it just shuffles data in a dict or so), it can and should be a normal function. On the other hand, if it needs to do IO, it should be an async function.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not an `async` function, then you don't need to `await` it obviously. Not every function you call inside an `async` function must be `async` nor must be `await`ed; you can call regular non-async functions from within an `async` function.

The entire asyncio model works around an *event loop*. Only one task can run at any one time, and the event loop coordinates what is currently running. An `await` inside a function suspends the execution of that function and allows another task to be run on the event loop. So, in this example:

```
async def caller():
    await bar()
    print('finish')
```

The execution goes like this:

1. `caller()` is called and scheduled on the event loop, which will execute it as soon as an availability exists.
2. It calls `bar()`, which schedules its execution on the event loop.
3. The `await` suspends the execution of `caller`.
4. The event loop executes `bar`; let's say it's making a network request, so nothing will happen until that response returns, the event loop is free to run any other scheduled async tasks…
5. The network response returns, the event loop resumes the execution of `bar`.
6. `bar` ends, the event loop resumes the execution of `caller`.

`await` exists to coordinate the sequence in which asynchronous tasks are run and what task depends on the result of what other task.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid #2 and #3 are in fact not correct. Assuming `bar` is defined with `async def`, just calling `bar()` doesn't schedule execution in the event loop, it just constructs the coroutine object. If one neglected to await that object, the code in `bar` would never run and a warning would be emitted. (This is in contrast to Javascript async where it's perfectly fine to invoke an async function without awaiting it so it runs in the background; in Python one must use `create_task` explicitly.)

Comment: Also, `await` doesn't necessarily suspend execution, it just starts executing the async code, in this case the coroutine object, _allowing_ it to suspend. Suspension is in no way guaranteed, which is occasionally a source of [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816319/1600898).

Comment: @user4815162342, does this mean if you have all  blocking functions in the async function being called, it's execution will compulsorily not get suspended?

Comment: @SyedSaad Correct. An async function that doesn't await anything is a strong "code smell" indicating that it either should switch to async APIs ([`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) if it's talking to legacy blocking code) or that it shouldn't advertise itself as async to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

A coroutine can't run in the simply calling, it need to run in event loop.
The event loop will listen for the events that we add into the event pool and execute callback when the event fire
And when it execute the "await" part of the code, it probably means that there are some I/O bounds task, so that the event loop will go on next event, so that won't block the thread.